# CUDA, float precision

Tags: cuda, floating-point, gpu, precision

I am using CUDA 4.0 on Geforce GTX 580 (Fermi) . I have numbers as small as 7.721155e-43 . I want to multiply them with each other just once or better say I want to calculate 7.721155e-43 * 7.721155e-43 .

My experience showed me I can't do it just straight forward. Could you please give me suggestion? Do I need to use double precision? How?

Comment: I think you'll need to go to double precision for this, unless you can scale all your calculations up by some suitable factor ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The magnitude of the smallest normal IEEE single-precision number is about 1.18e-38, the smallest denormal gets you down to about 1.40e-45. As a consequece an operand of magnitude 7.82e-43 will comprise only about 9 non-zero bits, which in itself may already be a problem, even before you get to the multiplication (whose result will underflow to zero in single precision). So you may also want to look at any up-stream computation that produces these tiny numbers.

If these small numbers are intermediate terms in a mathematical expression, rewriting that expression into a mathematically equivalent one that does not involve tiny intermediates would be one way of addressing the issue. Or you could scale some operands by factors that are powers of two (so as to not incur additional round-off due to the scaling). For example, scale by 2^24 = 16777216.

Lastly, you can switch part of the computation to double precision. To do so, simply introduce temporary variables of type double, perform the computation on them, then convert the final result back to float:

```
float r, f = 7.721155e-43f;
double d, t;

d = (double)f;   // explicit cast is not necessary, since converting to wider type
t = d * d;
[... more intermediate computation, leaving result in 't' ...]
r = (float)t;    // since conversion is to narrower type, cast will avoid warnings
```

Answer (score 0):

In statistics we often have to work with likelihoods that end up being *very* small numbers and the standard technique is to use logs for everything.  Then multiplication on a log scale is just addition.  All intermediate numbers are stored as logs.  Indeed it can take a bit of getting used to - but the alternative will often fail even when doing relatively modest computations.  In R (for my convenience!) which uses doubles and prints 7 significant figures by default btw:

```
> 7.721155e-43 * 7.721155e-43
[1] 5.961623e-85
> exp(log(7.721155e-43) + log(7.721155e-43))
[1] 5.961623e-85
```